# How to append elements in REDOM.JS

Tags: javascript

I have DOM elementA , elementB and elementC .
ElementA is the parent and in it I want to add elementB and elementC inside it .

I have tried using setChildren but it overwrites elementB as it tries to insert elementC

A visual representation is

elementA > elementB and elementC

```
<div id="elementA">
      <div id="elementB"></div> 
      <div id="elementC"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See more at https://redom.js.org/#set-children

```
   var elements =  el('div#elementA',
       [
        el('div#elementB'),
        el('div#elementC')
      ]);

    setChildren(document.body, elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 elementA.appendChild(elementB);
 elementA.appendChild(elementC);
```